# Configuring static page with add_rewrite_rule gives 404 after navigating to Permalinks admin panel

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, rewrite-rules

I would like to create a simple static page in my theme which would then show some practical information on a certain event. The page would be served on the path `/practical`. For now, there are no variables required in the path structure. Note that the file should be able to call wp functions, such as including template parts and fetch a post with a specific query, so making this a static HTML is not what I want.

So I followed the steps in this blog post - https://macarthur.me/posts/creating-static-page-in-wordpress

In summary, I added following to `functions.php`

```
add_action('init', function () {
    add_rewrite_rule('practical/?$', 'index.php?static_template=practical', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
});

add_filter('query_vars', function($queryVars) {
    $queryVars[] = 'static_template';
    return $queryVars;
});

add_action('template_include', function($template) {
    $staticQueryVarValue = get_query_var('static_template');

    if(!empty($staticQueryVarValue)) {
        return get_stylesheet_directory() . "/static-templates/{$staticQueryVarValue}.php";
    }

    return $template;
});
```

I added the `static-templates/practical.php` file, currently just showing some gibberish.

When I navigate to `/index.php?static_template=practical` in the browser, it works and shows the file content correctly. So the `'query_vars'` and the `'template-include'` filters in the above snippet work as intended.

But the `/practical` path does not work and gives some strange behaviour:

- At first, it is redirected to `/practical/` and just shows the front page.
- I found somewhere that the **Admin** > **Settings** > **Permalinks** page flushes some cache and yes, the *second* I navigate to that page (so not even saving the settings), the behaviour changes. It shows the Apache 404 page. From this point, I can no longer go to the first behaviour without restarting my Wordpress instance.

When I am stuck in the second behaviour, it also occured to me that if I try to debug using for example `die("foo");` in the `'init'` hook, it is doing that, so the init is not run at that point. This debug "breakpoint" is hit when browsing to the front page though.

Could anyone help explaining what is happening or, even better, help me fix it to get it to work as intended?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd strongly advise against calling `flush_rewrite_rules` on the `init` hook for performance reasons, it should be enough just to visit the permalinks setting page in the admin area when you change the `add_rewrite_rule` calls ( just looking at it is enough, you don't have to resave ). Have you tested this with one of the rewrite analyser plugins to check that your rewrite rules regex actually matches the URL you're testing with, and that it's your rule that matches not something else?

Comment: I'd also defer to named functions instead of anonymous functions, anonymous functions are very difficult to remove via `remove_action` or `remove_filter`, can generate cryptic stack traces, and result in useless function names in debugging tools such as debug bar or query monitor

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell, thanks for the general advice. I wasn't aware of such plugins and installed the **Url Rewrite Analyzer** after a quick Google search. It immediately gave a warning that *Pretty permalinks are disabled, you can change this on the Permalinks settings page.* So I went there, picked another option than the default *Plain* option, and all of a sudden things started to work. I still don't really get what's happening though, and if this is a permanent fix rather than a lucky moment.

Comment: you cannot use rewrite rules with pretty permalinks turned off because rewrite rules ***are*** pretty permalinks, that's why all rewrite rules take the form `"nice looking URL regex" = "index.php?foo=bar"`

Comment: Ah, that explains everything, then. Thank you! If you want to make an answer out of it, I'd be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty permalinks and rewrite rules are the same thing, so you need to have them turned on for custom rewrite rules to work.